# How can internal software clip the 'From Software' channel on my Apogee Duet?

Tags: monitoring

I noticed this the other day: the Maestro mixer on my Mac was showing the 'From Software' channel clipping. It happened to be that Radium was playing internet radio and the volume slider on the Radium app was maxed. The sliders on the 'From Software' channel in Maestro were set to 0dB.

How can it be that an internal audio signal, completely digital, can clip a channel like this? Even dropping the sliders down on the channel didn't stop the clipping. I had to reduce the volume via the volume slider in the Radium application. That's got me scratching my head a bit and wondering if the app is really clipping it's audio line or if it's the Maestro mixer's channel strip monitors showing me something that isn't actually happening. I couldn't *hear* any discernable digital clipping on my monitors.

Here's a picture of it occurring...

[image: Maestro showing 'From Software' channel clipping]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that it counts 0dB (i.e. full-scale) as clipping - I've seen this before.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing -- that'd mean it's a Maesto monitor issue. I found it perplexing because I wasn't *hearing* clipping.

Comment: This is correct.  Remember that your software has no way of knowing if it goes over the maximum value... just if it hits that maximum value, because that is the maximum value.  0dB in this case is clipping.

Comment: @Brad - Only multiple successive samples at 0dB would result in audible clipping - I think this is how some digital meters show clipping (i.e. only if 2 or more successive samples max out).